# Is there a way to pass through configurations to Nginx Ingress Controller

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I’m wondering if there is any way apart from ingress annotations to pass configurations into the Ingress-controller pod.

Specifically I want to inject the “ssl_password_file” option, but I cannot find an Ingress annotation to do so.

Any help would be appreciated!

I am running the Nginx Ingress Controller on an AWS EKS cluster.

Comment: Hi CZchizhang, welcome to SO. What is wrong with using [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet:`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet)? The [`ssl_password_file`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_password_file) can appear at the `server {}` level, and nginx ingress uses one `server{}` per ingress v-host

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't come across this annotation looking online.